# Como mostrar un grafico con pygal en QMainWindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy tratando de mostrar un grafico x en una QMainWindow utilizando pygal sin embargo no se muestra el grafico, este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate
import pygal


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.bar = pygal.Bar()
        self.bar.add("Tabla", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
        self.bar.render()

app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
p.resize(900,600)
app.exec_()
```

Ya intente tambien utilizar un frame pero no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygal`](http://pygal.org/en/stable/index.html) es una libreria que sirve para generar imagenes en formato svg asi que una opción es usar [`QSvgWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgwidget.html):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSvg
import pygal


class Principal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        svg_widget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(svg_widget)

        bar = pygal.Bar()
        bar.add("Tabla", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
        data = bar.render()
        svg_widget.load(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    p.resize(900,600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me sale un error AttributeError: module 'pygal' has no attribute 'Bar'

Comment: @Revsky01 que extraño, ¿que version de python estas usando? ¿has podido testear los ejemplos de pygal?, ¿por que me señalas esto despues de una semana?¿alguna vez te funciono?

Comment: es version 3.6.2, si los he testeado,

Comment: @Revsky01 si al testear te ha funcionado entones mi sospechas es que estas usando PyQt5 en un python donde no instalaste pygal. Por favor respondeme todas las preguntas.

Comment: pygal si lo tengo instalado, ya que solo tengo una version de python instalada, apenas pude provar este codigo, sin embargo lo marque como correcto por que a simple vista no le encontre falla

Comment: @Revsky01 ¿has podido testear los ejemplos de pygal y te ha funcionado?, pues debes de testearlo cuando alguien publica una respuesta, uno invierte un tiempo para hacerlo y espera lo mismo de usted ¿no crees?

Comment: @Revsky01 si te ha funcionado los ejemplos de pygal, en uno de ellos usa Bar que yo recuerde por lo que no deberia lanzarte ese error, asi que yo no te podre ayudar en nada ya que no puedo reproducir ese comportamiento.

Comment: @ellyanesc, si tienes razon, disculpa esta ocasión no pude testearlo al instante, y encontre el problema. La version de python que tengo no es compatible